# Identifying which user has done the survey - Limesurvey

Tags: limesurvey

Is there any way by which i can see which user has given me what answers. I want see the all users who have undergone through survey.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the manual - Browse Survey Results - https://manual.limesurvey.org/Browsing_survey_results